# Rails-way to execute one-off task on Rails server startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, foreman

I have Rails 4.2 application and I want to execute some one-off code when server starts.

My first approach was to use initializer in `config/initializers` to run the code. But in this case code is being executed also for all the rake tasks and Sidekiq process.

So I've created a rake task to run my code. Now I wonder how to execute it along with rails server startup. Of course, I can create a shell script that will execute my rake task and then start the server. But is there any rails-way to achieve this?

[Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) is another approach [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811555/rails-3-execute-initializer-only-for-server-start) by SO, but it's not working for me as my task is not a daemon and the process terminates immediatelly after completion. Apparently all the processes in Procfile have to be daemonized.

Comment: Hi, i have no idea but have you tried to call the rake in config.ru ?

Comment: Why don't you wrap your server startup and rake task in a shells script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be achieved with Foreman by running in the same process as daemonized task (e.g. with `rails server`).

If one-off taks is `rake lego:update_all`

Then corresponding Procfile is

```
web: rake lego:update_all && rails s
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq
```